# How can I know the namespace of a 'serviceprovider' class in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: html, laravel

I use **Laravel 5.2**. I found the error message...

Fatal error: Class 'HTML' not found (View: D:\Websites\htdocs\eloquent\resources\views\nerds\create.blade.php)

To solve this problem, I use the following command...

> composer require illuminate/html

and update **Composer**

The Path of the 'Service Provider' I downloaded is ...

> vendor > illuminate > html > HtmlServiceProvider.php

In the app.php file the following line is not solving the problem.

> Illuminate\html\HtmlServiceProvider::class;

What should I write instead?

Would anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines inside `aliases` in `app.php`. The code should look like this

```
'aliases' => [
    // other aliases
    'Form' => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'HTML' => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
]
```